# JAX -WS web services

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am using [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) web services in my java application. Whenever there is any change in my web services. My client needs to be updated, the client is a desktop application. which is distributed to user on internet. I am New to web services.

What technique/method i should use that my client should be automatically update able. Currently if there is change in my web service,

i update my webservice, deploy on server, and then update my client ,

i mean i update my web service stub on client side and then recompile my client, create Jar from my client and then distributes to my users.

What is the best way, that my stub should automatically update if there is minor update on web service.

Comment: Not sure there's any minor change. Using stub means its mandatory regeneration each time web-service description somehow changes. Of course if are a not going to make meaningless changes like swapping parameters of operations or renaming them.

Comment: Use java Webstart or - if using a java ee server - the client facility.

Comment: use jnlp (netbeans is good IDE for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use top-down approach to web service development. It means that you can develop WSDL document first and then generate API classes that you can use in client application and in implementation. Currently I use this technique. I think that it is impossible to automaticaly update client when WSDL document was changed, but when you use top-down approach your client can produce compile time errors, which can indicate that you change WSDL. But some changes does not lead to errors in compile time and will be found only in runtime (for example, adding parameter to request does not generate any error and client application simply ignores it). Nevertheless, it is much easy to generate API classes from WSDL once and use them for client and for implementation at the same time.